# Agrupar valores de um array multidimensional com mesmo valor e exibir numa tabela

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, mvc, array-multidimensional

Bom dia,

Eu tenho um array multidimensional, mostrado a seguir:

```
    array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#35 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "73"
        ["valor"]=>
        string(6) "200.00"
        ["compra_nome"]=>
        string(8) "Chaveiro"
        }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#36 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "74"
        ["valor"]=>
        string(6) "500.00"
        ["compra_nome"]=>
        string(17) "Pulseira"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#37 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "74"
        ["valor"]=>
        string(6) "200.00"
        ["compra_nome"]=>
        string(14) "Chave de Fenda"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#38 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "74"
        ["valor"]=>
        string(6) "100.00"
        ["compra_nome"]=>
        string(15) "Chuveiro"
        }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#39 (3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "75"
        ["valor"]=>
        string(6) "100.00"
        ["compra_nome"]=>
        string(14) "Lampada"
        }
    }
    }
```

Eu preciso armazenar em um array os valores que o id, com isso eu precisaria fazer um foreach para montar uma tabela com os valores, devendo ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código de PHP:

```php
$clientes = $this->Oportunidades_model->buscaClientesComCondicoes($data);
$clientes_array =  array();
        foreach ($clientes as $key => $value) {
            // var_dump($value->codigo_cli);
            $clientes_array[] = $this->Oportunidades->buscaCompras($value->codigo_cli,$data);
        }
```

**PS**: A variavel que traz o o array multidimensional no inicio da pergunta é  **$clientes_array**
Sem ideias ;/

Estou utilizando PHP com CodeIgniter mas pode ser php puro tambem..

Edit: está retornando com seu codigo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisaria que retornasse 3 tabelas e junta-se os registros do 73,74,75 em 3 tabelas diferentes igual a imagem a cima;

Answer (score 0):

Amigo seu array inicial já possui a lista ordenada pelos ids, você só precisa percorrê-lo e montar a tabela.

```php
<table>
    <thead><th>ID</th><th>VALOR</th><th>COMPRA NOME</th></thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($clientes_array  as $items):?>
            <?php foreach($items as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php print $item->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $item->valor; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $item->compra_nome?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Caso queira agrupar o registros pelo valor:

```php
$lista = [];

foreach ($clientes_array as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!isset($lista[$item->valor]))
        {
            $lista[$item->valor] = [];
        }

        $lista[$item->valor][] = $item;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead><th>ID</th><th>VALOR</th><th>COMPRA NOME</th></thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($lista as $items):?>
            <?php foreach($items as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php print $item->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $item->valor; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $item->compra_nome?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua respostsas vinicius! Eu coloquei um edit no POST mostrando como está ficando. São 3 ids diferentes e e 6 tabelas. Eu precisaria que fossem 3 tabelas com os respectivos ids, e os registros que são do mesmo ID ficassem na mesma tabela. Ou seja tabela id 74(possui 3 registros) ai nessa tabela vai ter os 3 registros do ID 74.